# Android surface flinger

Tags: android

I want to know whether the surface flinger knows anything about the clickable regions on the current screen or surface flinger just displays the final screen and it knows nothing about the clickable regions and the windowmanagerservice dispatches the input to the window which is on the top and it does whatever it has to do with the input?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SurfaceFlinger just displays the final screen by compositing the various surfaces given to it. WindowManager handles the clickable regions, input events, z-order, etc...